# ma5603 - how to get ont port configuration via display command

Tags: huawei

how can i get the configured native vlan beside the ont-srvprofile from a display output which is not display current config ?

I do have the ont-srvprofile configured as transparent but the native vlan must be configured per ont port. therefore I run ont port 10 0 native  vlan ....
But I dont see this in any ont info output

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface gpon [frame]/[slot]
display ont port attribute [port] [ontid] eth [ethernetPort]
```